# automated email sending failure

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I am using [this article](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) to help me send automated emails, but I am having an issue in which nothing seems to be happening and no errors are generated.

I used AsyncTask but it is not sending the mail at all.

> public class Sender extends AsyncTask< Void, Void, Void> {
>
> ```
>   private Exception exception;
>
>   protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
>
>       Log.v("aws", "OPEN   asa");
>
>       Mail m = new Mail("email@email.com", "password");
>       String[] toArr = {"to@mail.com"};
>       m.setTo(toArr);
>       m.setFrom("from@gmail.com"); 
>       m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an >Android device."); 
>       m.setBody("Email body.");
>
>         try { 
>           //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 
>
>           if(m.send()) { 
>               Log.v("aws", "OK SENT");
>           } else { 
>               Log.v("aws", "NOT SENT");
>           } 
>         } catch(Exception e) { 
>             Log.v("aws", "EXCEPTION . NOT SENT"); 
>         }
>       return null;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       return null;
>   }
>
>   protected void onPostExecute(Void... arg0) {
>       // TODO: check this.exception 
>       // TODO: do something with the feed
>    }
> ```
>
> }

I have used `new Sender().execute();` to execute the task, but nothing is happening and no errors are being thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Code has two `doInBackground` such that second overridden my working `doInBackground`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, you have two `doInBackground()` methods in your code, and the `@Override` version is what gets executed by the `AsyncTask`. Just move the code from the wrong `doInBackground()` version to the right one and delete the wrong one.